# PowerPoint VBA, "For each" troubleshooting help (with copy pasting)

Tags: vba, loops, powerpoint, shapes

I'm trying to do a loop which would copy shape and then paste it to the following slide.

I have 20 Slides in which 19 of them have a Shape (group of shape actually, textbox, imgs etc..) at the coordinates .Left = AA and .Top = BB.

```
    Dim Sld As Slide
    Dim Shp As Shape

For Each Shp In Sld.Shapes
        With Shp
            If .Type = msoGroup _
                And .Left = AA _
                And .Top = BB _
                Then
                    .Cut

                With ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex + 1)
                    .Shapes.Paste
                    .Left = CC
                    .Top = DD
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next
Next Sld
```

This is my current code, and the probleme I have is that It will cut and paste all the shapes, but not in the next slide following the slide where the Shape was first copied.

It will paste them all in following slide of where I was when I run the macro.

For exemple If I'm on slide 4 and I run the macro, all the shapes in .Left = AA and .Top = BB will be pasted in Slide 5 at .Left = CC and .Top = DD

What I would like is If the shape is cut in slide 1, I would like it pasted in slide 2 at .left = CC and .Top = DD. If the shape is in slide 2, I would like it pasted in Slide 3 at .left = CC and .Top = DD. And so on.

Thank you in advance for your help. I've been stuck on this for over a week.

Comment: Your sample code does not compile. You are mixing references to `Sld` and `Shp` (`For Each Shp In Sld.Shapes` and `Next Sld`). Also, a `Slide` object does not have a `Left` property, so the lines `.Left = CC` and `.Top = DD` fail. Is it your actual code or just an example? That said, if the `Sld` object is a reference to an actual `Slide` object, it has a `SlideIndex` property which holds the index of the slide where the shape was cut from - just add 1 to it.

Comment: This is my actual code.
You're right, .left and .top fail, but it was working beofre I made a few changes.

Im not to sure why Im mixing references. What I'm trying to do is
For each shape in the current slide, if the shapes is at the corrdinates the cut and paste it to the next slide. Then on this next slide if a shape is a the corrdinates, reapeat. I tried to use the slideIndex +1 but I'm doing it wrong because it does go to the Slide N+1, N being the slide where the shape is cut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this working (tested) example help?

```
Option Explicit

Const AA = 0
Const BB = 0
Const CC = 100
Const DD = 100

Sub MoveShapesBetweenSlides()
  Dim Sld As Slide
  Dim Shp As Shape
  For Each Sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each Shp In Sld.Shapes
      With Shp
        If .Type = msoGroup And .Left = AA And .Top = BB Then
          .Cut
          ' Create an index to the next slide
          Dim lNextSld As Long
          If Sld.SlideIndex = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count Then
            lNextSld = 1
          Else
            lNextSld = Sld.SlideIndex + 1
          End If
          ' Paste the shape from the previous slide to the next slide and reposition it
          With ActivePresentation.Slides(lNextSld)
            With .Shapes.Paste
              .Left = CC
              .Top = DD
            End With
          End With
        End If
      End With
    Next Shp
  Next Sld
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted and works as I wanted. But still I don't understand why in your case it does go to the following slide each time and in my case it doesnt work. In your case, the variable lNextSld is set, then if the current slide that the macro is working on is the 1st one, then lNextSld = 1, if not then it's +1. 
But everythime that the loop restarts, shouldn't the variable restart also? I'm not very clear, but I'm trying to understand how it works differently from my original code so  I don't just stupidly copy paste.

Comment: The variable lNextSlide is set to the index of the current slide in the loop +1 unless the slide is the last in the deck in which case it forces the next slide to be the first slide.

Answer (score 0):

The following cuts and pastes the shapes and repositions them - starting from the next to last slide so as not to cut a shape that was just pasted:

```
Sub MyTestSub()
    Const OLD_DISTANCE_A As Long = 10
    Const OLD_DISTANCE_B As Long = 10
    Const NEW_DISTANCE_C As Long = 100
    Const NEW_DISTANCE_D As Long = 100

    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim oShp As Shape
    Dim oShpRng As ShapeRange
    Dim lCurrentSlideIndex As Long

    '***** go through all slides except the last one - start from the next to last
    For lCurrentSlideIndex = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(lCurrentSlideIndex)

        For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
            '***** is it in the position we are interested in?
            If oShp.Left = OLD_DISTANCE_A And oShp.Top = OLD_DISTANCE_B Then
                oShp.Cut

                '***** paste on slide + 1 (without checking that it exists!)
                Set oShpRng = ActivePresentation.Slides(oSld.SlideIndex + 1).Shapes.Paste

                '***** set new position
                oShpRng.Left = NEW_DISTANCE_C
                oShpRng.Top = NEW_DISTANCE_D
            End If
        Next oShp
    Next lCurrentSlideIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is also working as I wanted. but same question as above. Shouldn't the variable lCurrentSlideIndex be reset everytime the loop restarts?
And I have to read about "Step" as it is the first time I see this. (new to vba)

Comment: Yes and *it is*. The variable `lCurrentSlideIndex` is defined in the sub `MyTestSub`, so it is created everytime `MyTestSub` is called and is gone when the sub exits. In this case, `Step -1` tells the for loop to decrease `lCurrentSlideIndex` by one for each iteration, since we (I) want to step through the slides beginning from the end.

Comment: Got it, so as long as the loop runs, and the Sub did not end, the variable keeps on changing according to the code.